# SQL: DB table in my plugin print UTF-8 (×ž×•×‘×¨×©) charsets and not hebrew

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have created custom table in wordpress db to use my plugins needs.

i have campaigns with hebrew names, this saved to column (varchar(100)  utf8_unicode_ci )
in the DB i dont see hebrew but this: ×ž×•×‘×¨×©× ×“×™×.

also when i try to get this data from DB by this code:

```
global $wpdb;
$list = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ExternalCustomerId, AccountDescriptiveName FROM My DB GROUP BY AccountDescriptiveName;" );
foreach ($list as $key => $object) {
echo $object->AccountDescriptiveName;
}
```

i get ×ž×•×‘×¨×©× ×“×™×

my webiste have meta charset="utf-8" /> in

How can i get regular hebrew and not this UTF-8 charset?

Comment: What language character do you want to show?

Comment: Hi @Miya G, Hebrew as i write.

Comment: Okay, The same issue was faced by me, I think I have resolved the above at my end.  Can you please share your Database character set?

Comment: Hi @Miya G, DB is UTF-8 and the table is utf8_unicode_ci